# Timestamp with timezone in relation to UTC

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, timezone, utc, timestamp-with-timezone

I have this timezone `America/Sao_Paulo` in my database.

Example:

```
2017-02-07 10:06:32.157564-02
```

---

```
ts = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), index=True, server_default=func.now())
```

My question is, this mean that `10:06:32` already have less two hours than UTC? So -2 is just informative and this is the correct time.

Or It means that we need to subtract two hours (-2) from `10:06:32` to get the correct hours to the timezone for `America/Sao_Paulo`?

Comment: @VaoTsun Your comment is confusing.

Comment: sorry for confusing. I posted answer with example. hopefully it will be clear

Comment: @VaoTsun you mean *add*.  The value is local time.  One inverts the sign to get back to UTC.

Comment: yes it surely inverts to get UTC. I removed the comment so it would not confuse any more. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm in GMT+2 atm, so to mockup your tz, I set it to yours and then select your time ATM and time in UTC same moment:

```
t=# set timezone TO 'America/Sao_Paulo';
SET
Time: 0.222 ms
t=# select now() sao_paulo, now() at time zone 'UTC' utc;
           sao_paulo           |            utc
-------------------------------+----------------------------
 2017-02-07 13:54:35.112992-02 | 2017-02-07 15:54:35.112992
(1 row)

Time: 0.163 ms
```